# Автоматическое создание изображений из html страниц

Tags: алгоритм, php

У меня есть много страниц на сайте. Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске скрипта у меня сделались скриншоты всех страниц , имеющихся на сайте в хорошем качестве?
Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться? На чем написать этот скрипт?

UPD: Вот такой есть сервис http://www.s-shot.ru/ - он делает скриншоты. Но качество их оставляет желать лучшего. 
Скажите, если писать вручную и использовать функцию для скриншот от виндоуса как написано в ответе ниже, качество будет аналогичным или другим?

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте, здесь описано очень не плохо, [как сделать скриншот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/62965/).